# model validation error ui notification

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

newbie in Web UI.
have a validation on some field, I manage to show the error message and everything is ok.

How do I have UI change in validation error - for example circle the field with red box so user will immediately see that? Is there some IF in the .cshtml that I miss?

```
<section class="form-field">                
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class = "field field182" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null)
```

BTW - I see I have some bootstrap 3.0.0 reference in the project so if it will be easier hint me how to circle my form with red box...

Comment: Are you using Required attribute on the FirstName property? This should mark the field as required, then the field will be marked as red

Comment: When the validation is triggered, you can inspect the field using Firebug or similar and you should see that an 'error' class has been added. I'm guessing that because you're using Bootstrap, you don't have the default css for the error class so you don't see a change. Bootstrap will probably have a different error class name.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the field `FirstName` in your Model as `[Required]`. for e.g.

```
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```